# How to work around 10 limit for make_shared in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, shared-ptr

While utilizing new features of C++10 on some old code, I ended up with the problem that I cannot call `make_shared` that takes 12 parameters. I remember Microsoft's STL talking how they use emulation for `make_shared` and that 10 is maximum.
Obviously refactoring code just for this is out of the question, so basically my question is - Is there a way to get more than 10 params to `make_shared` in VS 2010.

Comment: Try adding `/D_VARIADIC_MAX=12` to the compiler options. I remember reading you can only increase it to 10, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @Praetorian http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx says the limit is 5 to 10 inclusive.

Comment: "*Obviously refactoring code just for this is out of the question*" How about refactoring the code because a constructor with 10 parameters is clearly begging for some refactoring?

Comment: @NicolBolas actually no. I dont want to give away expert trade secrets(of the gurus that wrote 12 arg ctor class :D) but trust me it is not a regular class, more like a msg. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
make_shared<foobar>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
```

can be replaced with

```
shared_ptr<foobar>(new foobar(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12));
```

In C++11, std::make_shared is actually a performance optimization over creating an object using the second method, because it only performs one memory allocation instead of two, but once you get past 10 variables, you don't have much choice about which to use.

Comment: Doh, Im so stupid... shared_ptr<T> doesnt care about number of T ctor args, only fake variadics in make_shared are the limit... tnx applied and testing it now, from what I see it works. :)

Comment: `make_shared` is also useful for writing exception-safe code.  If you use this way, give every `shared_ptr` a name, don't pass them around as temporaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `make_shared` for its efficiency advantages then you can still do so:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <redi/index_tuple.h>

template<typename X, typename... Args>
  std::shared_ptr<X>
  make_shared_TO_THE_MAX(Args&&... args)
  {
    struct Wrapper
    {
      X x;

      template<typename... T>
        Wrapper(std::tuple<T...> targs) : Wrapper(targs, to_index_tuple<T...>{}) { }

      template<typename T, unsigned... I>
        Wrapper(T targs, index_tuple<I...>) : x(std::get<I>(targs)) { }
    };

    auto wrapped = std::make_shared<Wrapper>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    return std::shared_ptr<X>(wrapped, &wrapped->x);
  }
```

This bundles up the constructor arguments into a tuple of references and passes that to `make_shared`, so it doesn't matter that `make_shared` can't handle 10 arguments because it only gets one.  Instead of `make_shared<X>` it uses `make_shared<Wrapper>` which will allocate space for a `Wrapper` (which is the same size and layout as its member of type `X`) and construct it with the argument tuple.  The `Wrapper` constructor delegates to another constructor which expands the tuple to pass to the `X` constructor.

Finally, it uses the `shared_ptr` aliasing constructor to return a `shared_ptr<X>` that shares ownership with the `shared_ptr<Wrapper>` but stores the address of the `X` object.

`<redi/index_tuple.h>` is [my own header](https://gitorious.org/redistd/redistd/blobs/master/include/redi/index_tuple.h) but I'm trying to get [something similar](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3493.html) standardised for C++14.

This can be done without variadic templates too, but is more work. Here it is for two arguments, just add ten more for twelve!

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

template<typename X, typename Arg0, typename Arg1>
  std::shared_ptr<X>
  make_shared_TO_THE_MAX(Arg0&& arg0, Arg1&& arg1)
  {
    struct Wrapper
    {
      X x;

      template<typename T0, typename T1>
        Wrapper(std::tuple<T0, T1> targs)
        : x(std::get<0>(targs), std::get<1>(targs)) { }
    };

    auto wrapped = std::make_shared<Wrapper>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Arg0>(arg0), std::forward<Arg1>(arg1)));
    return std::shared_ptr<X>(wrapped, &wrapped->x);
  }
```

Comment: wait, isnt ... var templates? If so then :( because :" Is there a way to get more than 10 params to make_shared in VS 2010."

Comment: It doesn't pass more than 10 params to `make_shared`, that's the point. But it does use variadics. I was thinking the compiler supported variadics but the stdlib didn't, but I think that's only true for the latest compiler update. You could still do the trick above without variadics, just manually list the 12 arguments your type needs and then explicitly unpack the tuple with `std::get<0>(t), std::get<1>(t), std::get<2>(t),` etc.  If `tuple` also has a limit of ten you'd need to pass two tuples.